# Correct way of using JQuery-Mobile/Phonegap together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

What is the correct way (to this date) to use JQuery Mobile and Phonegap together?

Both frameworks need to load before they can be used. How can I be sure that both are loaded before I can use them?

Comment: please ! choose an answer !!!

Comment: even though it deserves it, I'm not going to +1 this until an answer is chosen <3

Comment: What is the actual problem being solved here - what if I just provided references to the required js files for jQuery and Cordova in my index.html and then redirect to say login page from a 3rd js file using jQuery's $.mobile.changePage? I mean what stops this design from working and why do I need the solutions outlined below? Is it because there are asynchronous loads inside jQuery and/or Cordova and my 3rd js file could be loaded even before the 2 frameworks are loaded? Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: @Mustafa for example you might try to access the database BEFORE the `ondeviceReady` event is triggered from your JQM code...

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You can use deferred feature of JQuery.

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
  deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}

$(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
  jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});

$.when(deviceReadyDeferred, jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded);

function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded() {
  // TBD
}
```

Comment: this answer should get more votes and be marked as the correct one.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more please? What's the hierarchy of file references look like? Thanks

Comment: Not only should this be the accepted answer, it should also be the template for cordova as it ships, callback hell is for a different era.

Comment: Please, could you add the order of the script loading, using latest version ??

Comment: jQM should be loaded after the code in this example. i.e: assuming the code is in a file called environment.js, the scripts should be loaded in this order: jquery, environment, jquery.mobile. Hope that helps.

Comment: For all those who say it doesn't work - the order of declaring script matters. First include jquery, THEN THIS CODE inside a script element, then jquery mobile js.

Comment: Please can you give us the order of scripts loading for this ? Because for me, this is not working fine (PG 3.3 & JQM 1.4).

Comment: What about `cordova.js`? Should it be loaded before or after JQM?

Answer (score 17):

Here's how it worked for me, based on the example above

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <title>InforMEA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dd = $.Deferred();
            var jqd = $.Deferred();
            $.when(dd, jqd).done(doInit);

            $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
                jqd.resolve();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
            function deviceReady() {
                dd.resolve();
            }

            function doInit() {
                alert('Ready');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me too but if I add  <div id="test-index-page" data-role="page">
 </div>  to the same page before html tag closes the page doesn't load and I get errors. I want to start using both frameworks using a third js file from the point both are loaded. How do I do that?

Comment: Of course I tried loading the 3rd js file that has business logic for my app in the doInit() but it didn't work. That file has event binding logic and function declarations e.g. $( document ).delegate( '#fakhera-index-page' , 'pageinit',function(event){ ... }. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7):

In order to use phonegap along with jquery mobile, you need to use it like this

```
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>

<!-- Adding viewport -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">

<!-- Adding jQuery scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Since jQuery Mobile relies on jQuery core's $.ajax() functionality,
 $.support.cors & $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages must be set to true to tell
 $.ajax to load cross-domain pages. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    });
</script>

<!-- Adding Phonegap scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"
    src="cordova/cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>

<!-- Adding jQuery mobile scripts & CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="jquerymobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>

</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Listener that will invoke the onDeviceReady() function as soon as phonegap has loaded properly
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();

        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackClickEvent, false); // Adding the back button listener    

    }
    </script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="something" data-ajax="false">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#something").on("pageinit", function(e) {

            });

            $("#something").on("pageshow", function(e) {

            });

            $("#something").on("pagebeforeshow", function(e) {

            });
        </script>

        <div data-role="header">            
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">           
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

As many people suggested using a deferred is an okay option as long as you don't care what order `deviceready` and `mobileinit` happe in. But in my case, I needed a few `pageshow` events when the application first loaded and `mobileinit` and by extension those `pageshow`/`pagebeforeshow`/etc events were all firing before `deviceready` finished, so I couldn't bind to them properly using a deferred on them. This race condition was not a good thing.

What I needed to do was make sure 'mobileinit' didn't take place until after '`deviceready`' was already fired. Because `mobileinit` fires immediately when you load JQM I chose to use `jQuery.getScript` to load it AFTER `deviceready` was already finished.

```html
<script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/async.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready',
    function () {
      $('body').css('visibility', 'hidden');
      $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
        app.init();
        $('body').css('visibility', '');
      });
      $.getScript('js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js');
    },
    false
  );
</script>
```

The reason I'm hiding the body is that a side effect of this method is a half second of visibility of the original HTML document before jquery.mobile loads. In this case hiding it an extra half second of empty space is preferred to seeing the unstyled document.

Comment: +1 on your answer for it inspired me to solve my problem with some slight change.  First,  move body.hide() code to very first line of onBodyLoad(); Second, move body.show() code to be after getScript( jQM_PATH); Because,  mobileInit() is called on each JQM page transition. Not ideal. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Can you just include the rest of your `index.html`

Comment: This did not work for me because cordova was removing all files there weren't included using the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it isn't necessary to use the deferred feature. (Maybe this isn't necessary with newer versions of phonegap?) I have this in the head of my index.html file and everything works fine. I do think that the order of including jquery, phonegap and jquery mobile are important.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <!-- Adding jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add Phonegap scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <!-- Add jQuery mobile -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <title>MY TITLE</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is work for me. base on dhaval,this sample when I learn using sqlite

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<title>Cordova Sqlite+Jquery</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">`

// Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
//
// At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-1.8.0.js has not.
// When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
// it will call the event `deviceready`.
//
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

// Populate the database 
//
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
}

// Query the database
//
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

// Query the success callback
//
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    //console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    $('#result').html("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
    var listval = '';
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        //console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
         listval += '<li>'+ results.rows.item(i).data + '[' + results.rows.item(i).id + '] </li>';
    }

    $('#listItem').html(listval);

}

// Transaction error callback
//
function errorCB(err) {
    console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

// Transaction success callback
//
function successCB() {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
}

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API
    //alert('ready');
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    //$('#result').html('hello');
}

</script>
  </head>
 <body onload="onLoad()">
  <div>result:</div><div id="result"></div>
  <ul id="listItem">
  </ul>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on @Jeffrey's answer, I found a much cleaner way which hides the HTML markup until JQM has finished processing the page and renders the first Page element, since I've noticed that 1/2 second flicker of bare markup before JQM renders.

You only need to hide all the markup with css...PageShow() by JQM will toggle the visibility for you.

```
//snip
<style type="text/css">
.hide {
  display:none;
}
</style>

//snip - now the markup notice the hide class
<div id="page1" data-role="page" class="hide">
     //all your regular JQM / html form markup
</div>

//snip -- down to the end of /body
<script src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
   document.addEventListener(
     'deviceready',
      function () {
         $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
         //any JQM init methods

       });
      $.getScript('js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js');
   },
   false);
</script>
```

Comment: tried your suggestion and it didn't work for me.  JQM pageshow won't show the hidden first page. Moreover, the standard html still show up before being hidden. I eventually made it work based on Jeffrey's solution with slight changed in timing. see my comment below his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on PG 2.3 and JQM 1.2, incl. Facebook Connect Plugin:

```
<head>
<script src="./js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        dataType : 'html'
    });

    var dd = $.Deferred();
    var jqd = $.Deferred();
    $.when(dd, jqd).done(function() {                

        FB.init({ appId: auth.fbId, nativeInterface: CDV.FB, useCachedDialogs: false });
    });

    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        jqd.resolve();
    });                        
</script>
<script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
    $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";

    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.support.cors = true;       

    $('[data-role=page]').live('pagecreate', function(event) {                      
        tpl.renderReplace('login', {}, '#content-inner', function() {                   
            auth.init();
        });
    });
</script>
<script src="./js/cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
<script src="./js/cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js"></script>
<script src="./js/facebook_js_sdk.js"></script>                     
<!--some more scripts -->
<script>        
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
        dd.resolve();
    }, false);                        
</script>  
<head>
```

Answer (score -1):

Loading of PhoneGap is slightly different than loading of jQuery. jQuery works more as a utility library so you include that and it is available for use immediately. On the other hand PhoneGap requires support from native code for proper initialization so it is not ready to use soon after included in the page.

Phonegap suggests to register and wait for `deviceready` event executing any native specific code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // jquery code here
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="lib/android/cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // write code related to phonegap here
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
    <h1>Phonegap Example</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more info check [doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)

Comment: But the problem is that i want to use phonegap stuff in my jquery code. In your example all jquery code would be run before phonegap is even loaded. Maybe if i put all the code inside onDeviceReady() function?

Like this:
$("#form").live("pageinit",function(event)
    {
//phonegapp stuff here
});

Comment: if your `#form` is the first page then you wont receive `pageinit` callback as it is too late