# Installing jquery mobile in phonegap

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct way of using JQuery-Mobile/Phonegap together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together)

do I have to install jquery mobile into phonegap so that it is included into the APK file? I'm using in the HTML file the google jquery library and would like to have he app functioning also offline.

also phonegap is working very slowly, is anybody else expiriencing this?

thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to install it, just follow the tutorial and copy jQM files into assets/www directory and rebuild android project so it can accommodate to phonegap libraries.

[This](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/) tutorial will help you learn how to create an apk file, but from your second question I think you know what to do.

Regarding your second question slowness is not do to phonegap but because of jQuery mobile. It is still a rather slow framework for mobile devices. iPhone 5+ is currently best mobile platform for jQM, for android only 4+ version. Look at [this](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-createelement) graphs, they represent jQuery performance differences between mobile phones browsers and their desktop variations. Notice a difference between mobile phones and desktop browsers, that is a main reason for phonegap sluggishness.