# JQuery mobile e-book Development

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am in the process of developing an e-book for various mobile devices. This e-book will involve mathematics and it is meant to serve kids in the junior school on tablets and smartphone. My aim is to use JQuery mobile to do this and then use Phone-gap to port it to various native applications that can be accessible through various platform such as android, iPhone, etc. I was wondering if there is any tutorial or help that one can get. It will be very useful if someone can point me to something similar that I can build upon. Please note that I want to use Jquery from the scratch.

Your help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

There are a lot of available tutorials.

Best of them can be found directly on Phonegap/Cordova web pages:

**Phonegap/Cordova installation and configuration:**

- MacOS Cordova + Android : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android
- MacOS Cordova + iOS : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS
- Windows/MacOS Cordova + Android : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

  and

  http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/building-a-phonegap-android-app-on-windows-cordova-2-2-0-with-eclipse/
- A lot of phonegap examples: http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials

**Jquery + Phonegap/Cordova**

- App example: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/
- Nothing complex but usable: http://pieterderycke.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/developing-mobile-applications-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile/
- Official jQuery Mobile + Phonegap know how : http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html
- And here's probably one of the best tutorials: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery_android/

**Rest:**

- My article about the Hybrid/native apps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069937/1848600
- My article on the Phonegap performance issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572977/1848600

**E-Book :**

- Here's am ebook reader plugin for phonegap: http://code.google.com/p/phonegap-ebookreader-plugin/

### Useful links:

[**JQUERY DOCUMENT READY VS JQUERY MOBILE PAGE EVENTS**](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)

**[JQUERY MOBILE AND HOW TO ENHANCE THE MARKUP OF DYNAMICALLY ADDED CONTENT](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**

**[HOW JQUERY MOBILE PAGE HANDLING AFFECTS JAVASCRIPT EXECUTION](http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/)**

[**SECRETS OF A GOOD JQUERY MOBILE PAGE ARCHITECTURE**](http://www.gajotres.net/secrets-of-a-good-jquery-mobile-page-architecture/)

Comment: Thanks. However, my challenge is not using any of these tools. My challenge is that I want to develop an e-book for mobile devices and I am considering using JQuery Mobile. So my question is: has something of this nature been done before? If yes is there any pointer or is there any tutorial that one can look into in relation to this.

Comment: You are not going to find that much specific tutorial because it is too much specific. But there's a working Phonegap plugin: http://code.google.com/p/phonegap-ebookreader-plugin/. Plugin can be easily implemented but first you need to go through basic jQuery + Phonegap tutorials. You will spend maybe few minutes implementing this plugin but few days (probably weeks) learning and implementing the GUI. Unfortunately this isn't something you can copy and paste, while this is an easiest way of implementing ebook reader app you have a lot of work in from of you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides) guides from Cordova as it will tell you how to get going with each platform.

I have also read the PhoneGap Essentials and found it a good way to get up to speed on the platform.

Total disclosure up front that I am on the product team, but Red Gate make a product that allows you to develop Cordova applications from within Visual Studio so if that is an environment that you are familiar with then you should check it out, it is called [Nomad for Visual Studio](http://vsnomad.com)

Comment: Thanks. However, my challenge is not using any of these tools. My challenge is that I want to develop an e-book for mobile devices and I am considering using JQuery Mobile. So my question is: has something of this nature been done before? If yes is there any pointer or is there any tutorial that one can look into in relation to this.

Comment: Ah I see. Well, there are lots of books on JQuery Mobile. One that I really enjoyed reading was [jQuery Mobile Up and Running](http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Mobile-Running-Maximiliano-Firtman/dp/1449397654/ref=pd_sim_b_2). I guess the complication with this kind of thing that in a framework that moves as fast as JQuery, books can become outdated pretty fast. I tend to use the JQuery Docs as a way to learn as they are excellent and full of good sample code.