# Programming only an app for iPhone Android

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, cordova, jquery-mobile

Hi I have to develop an app for Android and iPhone.
I know the language to develop for Android and to develop for iPhone, but if I want to create only one app for all platform, how can I use?
I have to create a simple app with some news taken from a server, this app can be downloaded from iTunes and from PlayStore but is the same app.
I know that there is PhoneGap, but I don't know if it can be done what I want.
Another way I thinked to use jQuery Mobile, but when I finish to develop how can I create an app? because I have ever use jQuery Mobile like a site on my server for mobile and not to create an app.
I suppose to create  a jQueryMobile app and when is finished to compile it with some program to create my App. I'm a  little bit confused, which is the best way and program to optimize develop time and to create only one multiplatform app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write one app natively for both platforms. Either you develop natively, but for each platform separately, or you use a framework like Phonegap. Then you write your code in HTML5 and JavaScript. You will still have to set up a project for each platform, but you can use the same HTML/JS files for both projects and simply drop them in. The only exception is: Any native code you write needs to be written for both platforms again (for example, all the standard phonegap plugins are written for each platform separately, but they already exist so you don't need to write them).

jQuery Mobile is something else, it's a framework for web development. You can use jQuery Mobile to develop the app you use in a Phonegap application (it's what I do).

Comment: A headsup: If you do choose Phonegap or a similar framework, keep in mind that Apple is very restrictive and you need to follow their guidelines. They will also deny any app that simply represents a mobile website -- your app has to really look like an app.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation!

Comment: Thanks, I know that I have to read a lot of page for restrictive guide of Apple, I think that the best solution in term of time and result is jquery mobile inside phoneGap if I have understand well right?

Comment: "Best solution" depends on your requirements. There are downsides to using natively wrapped web apps like Phonegap produces, but it certainly has a high level of comfort when it comes to cross-platform support (and to me it's easier to style my app the way I want to in HTML5 than natively). I developed an app with jQM + Phonegap that I just released today and overall I am happy. For a news reader app I think it is definitely a good choice.

Comment: yes isn't a difficult app, is the first of our web agency and is easy, the client load some news/events and the app print the news/events separated by category, I know that if I have to create a very difficult particular app I have to create a singular app for all the platform

Comment: Obviously I barely know your project, but seeing your doubts a hybrid app might really be a good choice for you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at my 3 previous answers on this question:

1. Frameworks and little something about them: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14166593/1848600
2. Native apps vs Hybrid apps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069937/1848600
3. Phonegap + jQuery Mobile tutorials: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14375842/1848600

I hope you will find your answer there.

Comment: I have seen your answer and I have already read something, I have done this answer to understand the best way and the more efficient way to develop a multiplatform app, thanks

Comment: I just read those posts too and they give a really good overview. I really wish JavaScript/CSS implementation was better, hybrid apps would benefit a lot

Answer (score 1):

Another framework option is the Apache Flex framework. You can use it to create native application for both Android and iOS. It is certainly capable of creating a simple new reader application.

Apache Flex has just become a top level Apache project and has just released version 4.9.0.

For more info see:
http://flex.apache.org (or http://flex.apache.org/v2)

If you do go down the framework path, and no matter which one you pick, it's likely you will still have to do some optimisation for each platform. Users expect different UI conventions on each platform. eg iPhone navigation is generally at the bottom, Android navigation is generally at the top.