# Jquery mobile page List-view content not getting updated

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to phonegap jquery mobile app. In my app i have some pages and each page gets its content as a list-view using json. Now content will load only once i.e when we click on the page for the first time and that's the same case for every other page. Later even if the json gets updated it won't be shown in the list. I can notice the updated list-view only after i logout from the app. and then again i login to the app. i.e content will get updated only after i restart the session!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this examples, one example uses xml to create a listview and other one uses a JSON file:

XML: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/

JSON: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/8uac7/

You are probably loading it in a wrong page event, if possible always use pagebeforeshow like this:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){        
   $.ajax({url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/23afca60ebf72f8d88cdcae2c4f31866/The Goonies",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });
});
```

Also take a look at my other article, it will give you a better understanding of jQM page events flow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010308/1848600

Comment: Thank you,Seems interesting. I will work on it :) For the time being what i tried is,I am removing the content each time whenever i am hiding the current page,and when i return back to the page i am reloading the content. Its working,but performance might be an issue here. Thanks for the reply..I will try your method.