# Phonegap jQuery: cannot call method confirm of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am creating a simple phonegap based application using jQuery mobile.

Here is the Header of my HTML

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/my.js"></script>
```

In the body after all my HTML code I have added

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to quit', 
        function(){
            if(button == "1"){
                 navigator.app.exitApp(); }
        }, 
        'QUIT TITLE', 
        'OK,Cancel'  
    );
</script>
```

I get the error

> 12-27 21:28:17.998: D/CordovaLog(17212): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   call method 'confirm' of undefined 12-27 21:28:17.998:
>   D/CordovaLog(17212): file:///android_asset/www/app.html: Line 227 :
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'confirm' of undefined

As you can see I have loaded all the necessary scripts, and I am calling the  `navigator.notification.confirm` inside `$(document).ready`

Not sure why I am getting this error. Please help.

Comment: are you calling it when the [device is ready](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your code inside script tag is not closed properly.

You are trying to use a Phonegap library before is is successfully loaded. ***$(document).ready(function() {*** should not be used with jQuery mobile (you will find more about this in a bottom link), nor it will tell you if phonegap libraries are loaded.

Your code should be initialized like this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

function deviceReady() {
    navigator.notification.confirm('Do you want to quit', 
        function(){
            if(button == "1"){
                navigator.app.exitApp(); 
            }
        }, 
        'QUIT TITLE', 
        'OK,Cancel'  
    );
}
```

You can find more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010308/1848600 and here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html