# jsignature on jquery mobile multipage not initiating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm loading 3 jsignature divs into my jquery mobile app. They display and work correctly when I load them into the certain pages:

[image]

But when they're loaded into other pages the div shows up with a squished height and is not responsive to touch:

[image]

I'm loading them with a document ready function at the bottom of the page, which seems fine:

```
<div id="info" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>NewF</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<form data-persist="garlic" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="_fid_14" id="_fid_14" />
</form>
</div></div>

<div id="sigemail" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Signatures & Email</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="fcmsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
<div id="gcsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
<div id="inspsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
<form data-persist="garlic" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
<br>
<p>What email address would you like the QAF pdf sent to?</p><input type="text"  name="_fid_210" id="_fid_210" />
</form>
    </div></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#fcmsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        $('#gcsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        $('#inspsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
    });
</script>
```

But when I change to this, so each signature loads in its own page, they loose size and functionality:

```
div id="info" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>NewF</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<form data-persist="garlic" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="_fid_14" id="_fid_14" />
</form>
</div></div>

<div id="sigemail" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<h1>Signatures & Email</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<form data-persist="garlic" encoding="multipart/form-data" encType="multipart/form-data">
<br>
<p>What email address would you like the QAF pdf sent to?</p><input type="text"  name="_fid_210" id="_fid_210" />
<a data-theme="a" href="#fcmsignature" data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" data-inline="true">Field CM Signature</a><br>
<a data-theme="a" href="#gcsignature" data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" data-inline="true">Contractor Signature</a><br>
<a data-theme="a" href="#inspsignature" data-role="button" data-transition="slidefade" data-inline="true">Inspector Signature</a>
</form>
</div></div>

<div id="fcmsignature" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<input data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-left" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="$('#fcmsig').jSignature('clear')"/>
<a href="#" data-theme="a" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">Save</a>
<h1>FCM Signature</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="fcmsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
</div></div>

<div id="gcsignature" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<input data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-left" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="$('#gcsig').jSignature('clear')"/>
<a href="#" data-theme="a" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">Save</a>
<h1>Contractor Signature</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="gcsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
</div></div>

<div id="inspsignature" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<input data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-left" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="$('#inspsig').jSignature('clear')"/>
<a href="#" data-theme="a" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">Save</a>
<h1>Inspector Signature</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<div id="inspsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
</div></div>


<script>
    $(document).ready( function(){
        $('#fcmsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        $('#gcsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        $('#inspsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
    });
</script>
```

I've tried using pageinit on the signature pages, but I get the same result:

```
<div id="fcmsignature" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
<input data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-left" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="$('#fcmsig').jSignature('clear')"/>
<a href="#" data-theme="a" data-rel="back" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-right" data-inline="true">Save</a>
<h1>FCM Signature</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<script>
$('#fcmsignature').live('pageinit',function(event){
    $('#fcmsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
});
</script>
<div id="fcmsig" style="width:600px; height:150px;"></div>
</div></div>
```

I'm not sure why they would work in one sub-page, but not another. Any thoughts?

- Update: A direct refresh of /index.html#fcmsignature shows the signature correctly. So the issue is somehow connected to the initiation of the signatures - which is why I tried pageinit (without success). I also tried data-transition="none" on the buttons, but no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
$('#fcmsignature, #gcsignature, #inspsignature').live('pageshow',function(e,data){
    $('#fcmsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
    $('#gcsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
    $('#inspsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
});
```

This syntax will take care that jQuery and jQuery mobile is loaded, and it will work only when pages **fcmsignature, #gcsignature, #inspsignature** are about to be show. And because you are using one signature per page use it like this:

```
$('#fcmsignature').live('pageshow',function(e,data){
        if($('#fcmsig').find('.jSignature').length == 0){
            $('#fcmsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        }
});

$('#gcsignature').live('pageshow',function(e,data){
        if($('#gcsig').find('.jSignature').length == 0){
            $('#gcsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        }
});

$('#inspsignature').live('pageshow',function(e,data){
        if($('#inspsig').find('.jSignature').length == 0){
            $('#inspsig').jSignature({'UndoButton':false,color:"#000000",lineWidth:1});
        }
});
```

jQM was not built to work with ***$(document).ready( function(){***. Read my other artice to find out why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010308/1848600

Comment: Thanks Gajotres. I tried 1) putting each snippet within the content of each signature page, 2) putting all three together in script at the bottom of the html doc, 3) putting all 3 together in the document ready function. None worked for me. Refreshing doesn't fix it either with these attempts. Thanks for the link. I've tried to be careful with $(document).ready( function(){ but the additional info helps.

Comment: Tell me do you have a single html page with multiple pages or 1 page per html file? What you could also try is to add an alert in every pagebeforeshow to see is it even triggering.

Comment: Its a single html page with multiple pages. I think its triggering something since the div shows the jsignature line, its just mis-sized and not functional.

Comment: can you change pagebeforeshow to pageshow or pagecreate. Maybe it is working like google maps mobile V3 api. It only works and shows in pagecreate event.

Comment: Sweet! Pageshow works, pagecreate doesn't. Only problem is every time that page is visited it creates another instance of the signature canvas. So if a user visits and closes that page, and then goes back to it, there will be 2 signature divs. How do I make the pageshow function happen only once?

Comment: give me a sec to find out what is jSignature doing to its div container.

Comment: Take a look now, I have changed my answer, now it has a check if jSignature styling has already been applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify for anyone else experiencing this issue, attaching jSignature to the "pageshow" event is what worked for me.

```
    $("#signpage").live("pageshow",function(e,data){
      if($("#signature").find(".jSignature").length == 0){
                    $("#signature").jSignature();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the other answers, **the jQuery live() function has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed since jQuery 1.9.** Now you will want to use the jQuery Mobile "pagecontainershow" event handler and check to see which page you are currently on, then perform the `if` block suggested in the other answers, as such:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function(evt, ui){
    var pageID = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id');

    if(pageID == 'signaturePage'){
        if($("#signatureDiv").find(".jSignature").length == 0){
            $("#signatureDiv").jSignature();
        }
    }
}
```

This method works as of jQuery 1.11.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.4.5.