# How to recognize page in JQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have one template which consist of several pages (data-role="page").

Also I have data which should be generated by script. Generated data depends on page, where script launch.

How I can get page id or another unique info about it in events, connected with changing pages?

I've tried pageshow event, but I cant get where page id.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ecXuk/

Also take a look at my other article on similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14010308/1848600

Here's a code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="test-button">Test button</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>   
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>            
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And js part:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    alert('Index Page');
});

$("#second").live('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    alert('Second Page');
});
```