# iPhone not loading js file

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

I have a little app I'm writing using jQuery and JQM.

The page loads an application javascript file.

However, when I update the js file on the server and open the app from the iPhone, the changes in the js file have not been loaded.

The HTML changes are loaded but not the js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js"></script>
```

Should I add a unique identifier to application.js?  so;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js?new1"></script>
```

and then

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="application.js?new2"></script>
```

Any thoughts?

**edit**

Changing the url like I did above works but I shouldn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I think Xcode don't support all file with extension *.js so just convert *.js file to *.txt format i think it should work.

Comment: this isn't xcode yet.  simply a web app using JQM.  Later it will be wrapped with PhoneGap and this issue should cease to exist

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together