# Phone Gap jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cordova

None of my jQuery/jQueryUI code works in PhoneGap when I build for Android but works in browser as well as Ripple. The problem is I don't really know how to debug it. I tried doing

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    alert("test");
  });
</script>
```

which again will pop up on Desktop but not on mobile, if I do regular JavaScript..

```
<script>
  alert("test");
</script>
```

it works just fine on both browser and phonegap application.

This is the order I am calling everything in.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jqueryui.js"></script>
```

I really hope somebody can help me figure this out. Please let me know if you need any more information..

Answer (score 0):

I have ordering that is different than yours.

The ordering that I have, that is working for me is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> //This order matters #1
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MY_CUSTOM_JS_RAWR.js"></script> //This order matters #2
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> //This order matters #3
```

Then within the js rawr file, I am doing something similar to the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821151/1775295), to make sure everything has loaded correctly.