# Embedded javascript won't execute using JQuery mobile on Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using JQuery mobile on Apache Cordova for android. Javascript between the body tags works, but javascript files that I link to in the header don't execute, even on the first page loaded.

I read a lot about problems with JQuery loading javascript due to the way ajax parses linked pages - however in this case embedded javascript isn't even working on the main page, and I can't find any answers to this problem

Here is index.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
});


function onDeviceReady() {
        alert('index js loaded successfully');

}
```

And here is index.html. The alert('index') works but alert('index js loaded successfully') does not appear

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">alert('index');</script>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js"></script>


<!-- Start of first page: #one -->
    <div data-role="page" id="one">

        <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Main Menu</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" >

               <p> content here </p>

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">
                <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: place them in head, not body.

Comment: tried that too and it also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You said embedded js isn't working on your main page yet your `alert("index")` works.  That's slightly contradicting and confusing.  Unless you're definition of embedded is different.

Regardless, I'm thinking that the javascript files aren't loading in the correct order.

For the project I use, I have something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> //This order matters #1
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MY_CUSTOM_JS_RAWR.js"></script> //This order matters #2
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script> //This order matters #3
```

Then, within the `MY_CUSTOM_JS_RAWR` file, I'm doing the method described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together/12821151#12821151).

Comment: sorry - you're right, i meant that the included js doesn't work