# Phonegap and JQM - order of deviceready and mobileinit?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Using the latest version of both Phonegap and JQM, how do I got about setting up the two events, `deviceready` and `mobileinit`?

(I have looked through the answers on here but they are outdated and give little info)

I am currently using the onload function, but there is severe lag - I can click a button that should fire a notification and it is delayed by several seconds.

Should I be using the jQuery `$(document).ready()`?

What is the correct order for `mobileinit` and `deviceready`?

Where should my own code go?

current code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
        $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
        $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    });    

    function onLoad() {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
      $(document).on('click', '.add-alarm', function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime(),
        _60_seconds_from_now = new Date(now + 5*1000);

        window.plugin.notification.local.add({
          title: 'title herre',
          message: 'my message',
          date: _60_seconds_from_now,
          sound: 'TYPE_ALARM'
        });
      });
    }
    </script>
```

`onLoad()` fired by

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
```

Comment: Wrap `click` listener` in `pagecreate` instead of `onDeviceReady()` and call `onLoad()`. `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () { click event here });`.

Comment: btw, `mobileinit` should go after jQuery.js and before jQM.js

Comment: What should I do with the deviceready event listener? I just tried wrapping the click event in pagecreate, it didn't work, in fact it made things worse. the alert didn't pop up.

Comment: Hmmm..good question. I dont know Phonegap, maybe you should keep it. But for jQM use _page events_ e.g. `pagecreate` to attach listeners/bind events.

Comment: The answer described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together/12821151#12821151) is personally what I use.  And it's not outdated.

Comment: If I used that solution, where do I put the configuration settings for JQM (the ones inside mobileinit typically)