# Cordova/JQuery mobile app not displaying pages correctly after being built

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile app using Apache cordova and jquery mobile. When debugging on my laptop everything looks correct and runs smooth but when I attempt to build to a device or look at an release build. It seems the data-role="page" isn't working and it just displays all of the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link href="../Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ManagerList.css">-->

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>HR Tips App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Opening Page css in index.css-->
    <div data-role="page" id="Opening" class="Opening">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div><img style="width:135px" src="images/Logo2.png" /></div>
            <div class="headerText"><span></span></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer" data-role="content">
            <div>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Opening Page2 css in index.css-->
    <div data-role="page" id="Opening2" class="Opening2">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="header">
            <div class="ui-mini ui-btn-left"><img style="width:100px" src="images/Logo2.png" /></div>
            <h4>HR Tips</h4>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" role="main" class="ui-content" id="Open2" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);background-image: url('images/Open2.png');">
            <div class="Start">Why this app?</div>
            <div class="Middle">
                <div class="MainOpen">
                    <span>
                        Managing relationships in the workplace<br />
                        can be not only rewarding but also<br /> sometimes chalenging...lorem ipsum dolor
                        <br />sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem
                        <br />sit amet, lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="EndingOpen">
                    <div>Lets get started</div>
                    <div><a href="Pages/ManagerList.html" data-transition="slideup"><img class="button" src="images/JLL_Icon_White_Next.png" style="border-width:1px;" /></a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ManagerLists.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I am out of ideas on how to proceed and any help would be greatly welcomed

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Correct way of using JQuery-Mobile/Phonegap together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945643/correct-way-of-using-jquery-mobile-phonegap-together)

Answer (score 0):

your mobile cannot access the jquery mobile .js and .css make sure you can access them. try using the CDN to make sure it's working